# Convert data inside a model to either a datatable or an array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, charts, google-visualization

I'm pretty new to c# MVC and would greatly appreciate if you can help me or at least give me an idea on how to solve this. 
So, I have this method that filters some information from my DB and returns a list (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Users.AspNetUser]).

```
 private static AspNetUser PopulateModel(string country, [Optional]int Agefrom, [Optional] int Ageto)
    {
        using (DBEntities entities = DBEntities()) //using ADOnet DB
        {
            AspNetUser model = new AspNetUser()  
            {
                WebUsers = (from c in entities.AspNetUsers
                            where c.Country == country || string.IsNullOrEmpty(country)
                            where c.AgeofUser >= Agefrom && c.AgeofUser <= Ageto || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Agefrom.ToString()) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Ageto.ToString())
                            select c).ToList(),
                Countries = (from c in entities.AspNetUsers
                             select new SelectListItem { Text = c.Country, Value = c.Country }).Distinct().ToList(),
                Ages = (from c in entities.AspNetUsers
                        select c.AgeofUser)
                                      };
           return model;
        }
    }
```

after that I'm trying to display a chart out of that filtered information, but googlecharts asks me for either an array or a datatable to link my data. My problem is that I don't find a way to convert that list to either a DT or an array. I'll leave you the script just in case.

```
<script>
        google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['table'] });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

        function drawTable() {
            //here google asks for data in a DT or array with the method arraytotable()
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(@Model.WebUsers);//here I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" for the bad input
            data.addColumn('string', 'Department');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Revenues');
            data.addRows(data1);
            var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

            table.draw(data, { showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%' });
        }
```

THANKS!

Comment: Looks like you are going to need to serialize your Model.WebUsers. Basically when your view gets rendered the .ToString() method is called on Model.WebUsers, so your script looks more like `...DataTable(System.List_SomeType)` which of course will fail. You need to serialize the data `JsonConvert.Serialize(Model.WebUsers)` so that it's in json format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code,

1. You're using the wrong format for initializing the visualizationDataTable and
2. You only need the WebUsers since it contains all the records already.

---

Here are 2 options:

- You could change your model in your controller to use correct format as shown here https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference. You'll be able to do this with .toJson/JSONStringify or `.toArray()`
- Or an easier option, use the empty initializer and create the variable row with the Webusers records. Modify your script to use the code below;

```
function drawTable() {
   // create row variable, replace u.Name with a string property from your model
   var rows = [
      @{
         foreach(var u in Model.WebUsers){
            <text>['@u.Name',@u.AgeofUser],</text>
         }
      }
   ]

   // use empty initializer
   var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

   // add your columns
   data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
   data.addColumn('number', 'Age');

   // add the row variable earlier
   data.addRows(rows);

   var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
   table.draw(data, { showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%' });
}
```

Comment: OMFG dude, this is so well explained that it deserves more than a best answer. I really appreciate it, IT WORKS!

Comment: THANK YOU AGAIN!

Comment: HAHA, glad I helped! Good luck with the project.